# DIV border displays oddly

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align some divs a certain way. To help debug what's happening, I decided to add borders to the divs to research how they were getting positioned. But the border looks pretty strange.
Here's the html:

[image]

Here's the CSS:

[image]

And here's the result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Define: "strange". And define: "optimal"

Comment: It seems like the div has a width (may be 100px) but does not have a height. Just type this in the JavaScript console *on this very page* and look at the heading: `$("h1").height(0).css("border", ".2em dotted #900");`

Comment: Could you paste the HTML and CSS as text, instead of pictures of text? Also, post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the code in action.

Comment: remove border- width and see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't funny (!!). The div appears to have `0` height, hence the top and bottom borders are touching each other, creating a funny (??) appearance.

The div appears to contain content but the content is probably floated or absolutely positioned, therefore it does not stretch the funny (!?) div vertically.

## [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Ewd4x/)

Comment: Height was the issue. Setting height resolved the problem. Thanks for all the help! And yea, apologize for posting pictures instead of the text. And I have learnt I could have used jsfiddle to post the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a good resource to learn about divs. They seem to be unintuitive in terms of floating, absolute/relative positioning etc. Thanks!

Comment: The behavior of CSS rules on HTML is well described on the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html); unfortunately, it is very hard to digest. I would suggest searching for CSS positioning and layout tutorials on Google. http://www.alistapart.com and http://www.cssjuice.com are my personal favorites. AVOID www.w3schools.com.

Comment: Thanks! I am checking out alistapart and cssjuice.

Answer (score 1):

Height is one way to do it, but its a bit hackey, another is to float the div that is surrounding other floated divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ewd4x/2/

Comment: Thanks! I really need to understand how divs work. It is not intuitive at all to me why floating affects borders.